# Kusto: Is it possible to prefix the columns coming from a specific table?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm performing a query and joining data from 3 different tables. In the final table, I would like to know which table each individual column comes from, since some of the column names repeat themselves. At the moment, I am doing a very long:

```
| project prefix1_column1=column1, prefix1_column2=column2
```

for each join.

In a perfect universe, I could add a parameter to the joins to specify a prefix but that doesn't exist. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is the best way to do it. For the feature you are asking for, please open a suggestion in the [Azure Data Explorer user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer).
You should also look at the [lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator) operator, which does not repeat the columns that are part of the join keys, while this will not solve your use case it will reduce the noise.